# How to charge a user to post a job listing in D7?

Tags: users, commerce, payment-gateways

I have a job board and want to charge recruiters for each time they post a job listing. I will be using paypal and would not mind using the [Commerce module](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) in Drupal 7. I'm comfortable building Rules, even very complex ones. What is the best way to let job recruiters and businesses manage purchasing credits to be granted permission to create a job posting content type?

Comment: On a side note, I don't think node-access is an appropriate tag for this post, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Commerce Credits](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_credits) gives the developer many different granular options to configure paying per content basis

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [Commerce userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_userpoints) and [Commerce Node Checkout](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_node_checkout). This will allow them to purchase credits to be applied to publishing nodes.